# Aren't English' "shoe" and French' "chaussure" related?

Tags: etymology, early-modern-english, french, etymological-fallacy

I was absolutely certain that *shoe* (en) and *chaussure* (fr) were cognates due to the obvious similarity between their first syllable, especially the pronunciation - that was until I looked them up on Wiktionary. There they claim that *shoe* has Germanic origin while *chaussure* comes from Latin.

Is it just a coincidence that the words in two languages, that have so much in common, for such a basic term (that very often are similar everywhere where Indo-European languages are spoken) are so similar but has completely different roots?

Comment: Indo-European is a very broad category. You're better off knowing that English has two broad historical strands (Latin/Germanic) and French has Latin. So, Indo-European is not very relevant in practical terms.

Answer (score 7):

No — they may coincidentally have similar forms now (though not identical), but they happen to have converged somewhat, not diverged.

*Shoe* [is from a Germanic root](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shoe) and hasn't changed much; it may ultimately be from a PIE root meaning "to cover".

*Chaussure* [is ultimately from Latin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chausse#fr) *calceus*, from *calx* "ankle".

If you know some Romance linguistics you can trace how /k/ became /tʃ/ and then just /ʃ/; how /al/ became /aʊ/ and then /o/; and how the end simplified to /s/. Meanwhile the English word has undergone a change from /sk/ to /ʃ/ and a vowel shift. That leaves us with /ʃu/ and /ʃo.../, but we began with /sko/ and /kalks/, clearly not very related.

---

<sub>Do forgive the very broad transcriptions and possibly erroneous for the Germanic root...</sub>